# Access VBA Multiple Sorting Criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

**The Case:** I have a form that has several fields of entry. A button contained within this form runs a query and generates a report based on the form entry fields.

I have created 3 comboboxes that will allow the user to sort the report on various criteria (ie. sort by Analyst name, then by Meeting Date, then by Ticker).

```
Combo Box 1 = Sort_By;
Combo Box 2 = Sort_By_2;
Combo Box 3 = Sort_By_3
```

**The Code:**

```
Private Sub Run_Query_Button_Click()
If Revisit_Check.Value = False Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Important Information Extracted"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenReport "Important Information Extracted", acViewReport
DoCmd.SetOrderBy Sort_By Sort_By_2 Sort_By_3
Else
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Revisit"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenReport "Revisit_Report", acViewReport
DoCmd.SetOrderBy Sort_By Sort_By_2 Sort_By_3
End If
End Sub
```

This code returns a syntax error. It does not sort on the three "sort by" criteria. If I use only on of the criteria in the following fashion:

```
Private Sub Run_Query_Button_Click()
If Revisit_Check.Value = False Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Important Information Extracted"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenReport "Important Information Extracted", acViewReport
DoCmd.SetOrderBy Sort_By
```

The code runs properly and sorts on the given "sort by" value. If instead of using the form field comboboxes to sort, I use the actual field names, for instance:

```
Private Sub Run_Query_Button_Click()
If Revisit_Check.Value = False Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Important Information Extracted"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenReport "Important Information Extracted", acViewReport
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Analyst, Meeting Date, Ticker"
   ...
```

Everything works fine as well. Why, when I use the three sort criteria, do I get a syntax error? How can I sort on these three criteria?

Comment: Are you asking why your code is working or....

Comment: Yes, what is wrong with my code? How can I get this multi criteria sort to work?

Comment: Okay, your post seems a little confusing regarding that is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Sort_By` is the values you get in the comboboxes you are seeking you will need something more like this:

```
Private Sub Run_Query_Button_Click()
    If Revisit_Check.Value = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Important Information Extracted"
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Important Information Extracted", acViewReport
        DoCmd.SetOrderBy Sort_By & ", " & Sort_By_2 & ", " & Sort_By_3
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Revisit"
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Revisit_Report", acViewReport
        DoCmd.SetOrderBy Sort_By & ", " & Sort_By_2 & ", " & Sort_By_3
    End If
End Sub
```

Notice the `& ", " &` to make it into the same kind of string as `"Analyst, Meeting Date, Ticker"` which you said had worked.  Otherwise your sort you are sending in the first time would look like this: `"AnalystMeeting DateTicker"`